# Top aligned the part of minipage

Tags: minipage

Question: In my work i am dealing with minipage and how can i shift above the second part of minipage? I mean top aligned the second part.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.7 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
%reduce top margin
\addtolength{\headsep}{-0.5cm}
%for line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{0.85}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{9pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{9pt}
    \begin{tabular}{Sc|Sc}
        2                      & 4096 \\ \hline
        2                      & 2048 \\ \hline
        2                      & 1024  \\ \hline
        2                      & 512  \\ \hline
        2                      & 256   \\ \hline
        2                      & 128 \\ \hline
        2                      & 64 \\ \hline
        2                      & 32  \\ \hline
        2                      & 16  \\ \hline
        2                      & 8  \\ \hline
        2                      & 4  \\ \hline
        2                      & 2  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 1  
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
    \begin{flalign*}
    4096&=\underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\\[6pt]
    &=2^3 \times 2^3\times 2^3\times 2^3\\[6pt]
    &=(2\times 2\times 2\times 2)^3\\[6pt]
    &=16^3
    \end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to add `[t]` also to the `tabular` environment. But then it is still not completely aligned, since the `flalign*` environment has some space above it. Use `aligned` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change two things:

- Add the option `[t]` also to the `tabular` environment. Otherwise it is vertically centered on the first line of `minipage`. With the `t` option the baseline of the tabular will be its first line.
- Use `aligned` with the `t` option instead of `flalign*`. `aligned` is similar to a `tabular` and forms a box, whereas `flalign*` displays its contents with additional space above it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.7 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
%reduce top margin
\addtolength{\headsep}{-0.5cm}
%for line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{0.85}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.35\textwidth}
    \centering
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{9pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{9pt}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{Sc|Sc}
        2                      & 4096 \\ \hline
        2                      & 2048 \\ \hline
        2                      & 1024  \\ \hline
        2                      & 512  \\ \hline
        2                      & 256   \\ \hline
        2                      & 128 \\ \hline
        2                      & 64 \\ \hline
        2                      & 32  \\ \hline
        2                      & 16  \\ \hline
        2                      & 8  \\ \hline
        2                      & 4  \\ \hline
        2                      & 2  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 1  
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hspace{\fill}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\textwidth}
    \(\begin{aligned}[t]
    4096&=\underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\\[6pt]
    &=2^3 \times 2^3\times 2^3\times 2^3\\[6pt]
    &=(2\times 2\times 2\times 2)^3\\[6pt]
    &=16^3
    \end{aligned}
    \)
\end{minipage}
\end{document} 


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7 in,bottom=0.7 in,left=0.7 in,right=0.7 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
%reduce top margin
\addtolength{\headsep}{-0.5cm}
%for line spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{0.85}

\begin{document}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{9pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{9pt}
    \begin{tabular}[t]{Sc|Sc}
        2                      & 4096 \\ \hline
        2                      & 2048 \\ \hline
        2                      & 1024  \\ \hline
        2                      & 512  \\ \hline
        2                      & 256   \\ \hline
        2                      & 128 \\ \hline
        2                      & 64 \\ \hline
        2                      & 32  \\ \hline
        2                      & 16  \\ \hline
        2                      & 8  \\ \hline
        2                      & 4  \\ \hline
        2                      & 2  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 1  
    \end{tabular}
    \qquad
    \(\begin{aligned}[t]
    4096&=\underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\times \underline{2\times 2\times 2}\\[6pt]
    &=2^3 \times 2^3\times 2^3\times 2^3\\[6pt]
    &=(2\times 2\times 2\times 2)^3\\[6pt]
    &=16^3
    \end{aligned}
    \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: its nice but can we get same result inside minipage?

Comment: @snehal What happens if you try?

Comment: It works perfectly.